# Issue with same url rewriting starting url but not same destination

Tags: php, apache

I try to implement URL Rewriting on my website and I have URLs with same start:

`/news/` --> all news and for example

`/news/5465/news_title/` --> One specific news but every time, it stops on the first rule.

I tried different flags but it seems that I don't have the write combination.

```
RewriteRule ^news/ index.php?action=allnewsdisp [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/ index.php?action=newsdisp&news_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

For now, just the first line is working.

Thanks